# What is expected value of SMD5-Password in freeradius' user config file?

Tags: radius, freeradius, freeradius2

I am using freeradius v2.1.12 on Ubuntu v14.04. Here is /etc/freeradius/users:

```
test    SMD5-Password := "{SMD5}xbYqJDY4gqVyE8Vhty//QnRlc3RpbmcxMjM="
```

I get this value by using the perl script from http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/418.html, I changed that script by replacing "secret" with "test" and "salt" with "testing123" because "test" is the my password and "testing123" is the shared secret.

Here is /etc/freeradius/clients.conf:

```
client test {
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        secret = testing123
}
```

I also changed /etc/freeradius/modules/pap to set "auto_header" to "yes":

```
pap {
        auto_header = yes
}
```

I am using radtest on the same machine:

```
radtest -x -t pap test test localhost 0 testing123
```

The radius server fails the password match:

```
#> freeradius -X
......
[pap] login attempt with password "test"
[pap] Using SMD5 encryption.
[pap] Passwords don't match
++[pap] returns reject
```

Do you see what is wrong?

Thanks!

[UPDATE] Thanks [Wumpus-Q-Wumbley](https://serverfault.com/users/193597/wumpus-q-wumbley), that is it. Remove "[SMD5]" and it works.

Comment: Wild guess: you should omit the `{SMD5}` prefix since the attribute name already has "SMD5" in it

Answer (score 0):

You've configured rlm_pap to search for a header but placed your hash in an attribute which is not checked for headers.

You should put your SMD5-Password in the `Password-With-Header` attribute, rlm_pap will then strip off the header and place the password in the correct attribute.

```
test    Password-With-Header := "{SMD5}xbYqJDY4gqVyE8Vhty//QnRlc3RpbmcxMjM="
```

Alternatively you can do what you did and remove the `{SMD5}` prefix.